# Moving PostgreSQL Analytics DB to Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

(My question is quite general and design oriented, but I suspect others are in the same boat I am in. If this question belongs somewhere else please let me know in a comment and I'll consider moving it.)

I currently have an Excel/VBA based application/UI that users interact with to analyze data. Let's call it 'Analyzer'. The data it uses is stored on a an on-premises PostgreSQL database VM server. The users interact with the Analyzer on Windows 7 desktops and the Analyzer queries the DB on the back end. There are only a handful of users who will use the system at the same time. It works great except that we want to dramatically increase the amount of data stored on the server and it doesn't have the resources.

So we have decided, for the reason above and other reasons, to move the DB to Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

My plan is to have my PostgreSQL DB on a Compute Engine on GCP and make an image of it each morning after the ETL processes are all finished for the night. I will use the same Analyzer program mentioned above and add functionality that will start up a Compute Engine instance on GCP using the PostgreSQL image once the user decides to use the Analyzer. Each user will use one Compute Engine and send multiple queries to it. At least for now. If the user has sent a query, but the query is not complete yet, a VBScript runs in the background waiting for the query to complete. This is possible because the query is sent through VBScript so the user doesn't have to have the Excel workbook open if they have a large query running. When it completes, the user opens the Analyzer workbook and accepts the results from the VBScript and the data is populated in the workbook for the user.

All of the systems that interact with GCP are written in Python and executed from VBA and VBSscript that are triggered by the UI/user within Excel.

We use a VPN tunnel to communicate with GCP.

The ETL processes, not really described above and present a different problem, work at night. We are still working with the first version of this ETL code so it isn't that efficient. I think the major issue is that it sends a lot of small queries to the DB. When I moved the DB to GCP the ETL processes ran, but were very slow to process. When I analyzed it, it seemed like the issue was latency due to slower communication between the ETL system that runs in our office (I can't change that for reasons that are out of my control) and GCP instances. I think if I reduce the number of small queries and send a thousand times less queries (send a handful of large queries) I can speed the ETL processes up a lot. For example, instead of this:

```
insert into daily_data (company_id, trade_date,daily_val,wh_calc_id,dates_id)
    values (5,'2017-11-15',100,436,1556537);
```

I would do this:

```
insert into daily_data (company_id, trade_date,daily_val,wh_calc_id,dates_id)
    values (5,'2017-11-15',100,436,1556537),
(6,'2017-11-15',500,436,1556537),
(7,'2017-11-15',700,436,1556537),
...etc... ;
```

My questions:

1. Although we have had a proof of concept fully functional DB on GCP, I am not familiar with GCP's entire ecosystem. I did some preliminary research on AppEngine, Sub/Pub, Cloud DataFlow, Cloud SQL, and they all seem to solve problems I don't have. For example, I don't need massive scalability, which AppEngine provides. I have all the code written to do most of what I want to do. Am I missing something?
2. Regarding the ETL processes, am I thinking about this correctly?
3. Are there any gotchas you can see with this design?